# Ant does not support for loop inside batchtest element

Tags: java, ant, junit

I want to define in command line what unit tests are to be run. Tests are defined in a logical structure based on Java packages. From the command line I want to define what Java packages are to be included in the test run (i.e. what tests to include).

In this way I want to loop through a tokenized list of path values, and include Java tests from these paths. However the batchtest element does not support nested for loops. How can I modify this to do what I want? So the amount of includes are as many as there are defined path values.

Updated:

I have defined target like this:

```
<target name="test">
    <property name="path" value="**"/>
    <junit fork="yes" failureproperty="true" forkmode="once">
            <formatter type="xml" />
            <classpath>
                <pathelement path="bin.path"/> 
            </classpath>

            <batchtest haltonerror="false" todir="${test.dir}"> 
                <fileset dir="/src/test/">
                    <for list="${path}" param="path">
                        <sequential>
                            <var name="path" value="@{path}"/>                      
                            <include name="**/${path}/**/*.java" />
                        </sequential>
                    </for>
                </fileset>
            </batchtest>
        </junit>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reguler expression.

For example;

```
<batchtest haltonfailure="yes" todir="/test">
        <fileset dir="/build/classes/"
                includes="**/TestBlaBla.class" excludes="**/BlaBla.class" />
</batchtest>
```

I hope it helps to you.

Comment: I am actually already using the fileset and regular expressions like "**/${path}/*.java. The problem is that $path is one token in the list so the list has to be looped in order to retrieve all the path values.

Comment: If you gave your exact "target", I could help for ant script.

Comment: I think <fileset dir="/build/classes/"
                includes="${path}/**/TestBlaBla.class" /> works for you no need a list path list to add one by one. root/** adds all path under roots to your classpath. Isn't it?